# python-sphinx autosummary table of contents

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use sphinx.ext.autosummary extension to document my package.

In **index.rst** I have:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 20
    :caption: References

    reference
```

And in **reference.rst**:

```
=============
API Reference
=============

.. autosummary::
    :recursive:
    :toctree: _api_reference

    mypackage
```

On the first page of the reference it creates a link table with only one entry for my package.
I would like to have a list of modules on the first page too (like auto-api extension does).
I could insert a `toctree` directive in the **reference.rst**, but in that case I have links for submodules twice in the side bar menu, and I have a link table with a package name in the first page of the reference and a table of contents after that with the same package name again.

Is there some way to place a table of contents with the package name and list of modules on the first page of the API reference generated with the autosummary?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this in Pyramid](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/index.html)?

Comment: @StevePiercy Autosummary shows only table with packages names. Sphinx autoapi shows pakages names and subpackages as table of contents